# How do I isolate select digits from a numeric key based on varying conditions?

Tags: sas

I am trying to extract a Country ID from a numeric product key which has 2 types:

For SAS EG 7.1
1. A 7-8 digit key with first 2-3 digits signifying country ID.
i.e. For US with Country code 36, product key= 36XXXXX

For INDIA with Country code 121, product key= 121XXXXX

2. A 13 digit key with 2nd, 3rd , 4th digit signifying country ID
   i.e. For US , Product key=X036XXXXXXXXX

For IN, Product Key= X121XXXXXXXXX

Using the following code to get this:

```
data want;
set have;
if length(key)>8 THEN COUNTRY_ID=substr(key), 2,3);
else COUNTRY_ID=substr(key,1,length(key)-5);
run;
```

It works for the 1st type with 7-8 digit product key but not for the longer 13 digit keys. It shows a decimal in the country id
i.e. For US, X036XXXX whereas it should be just 36.

Do I need to change data type??

Comment: The first `substr` in your code has a misplaced parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You should include some example data so that your question shows exactly what problem you're having, and what you're expecting, but I *think* all you need is to convert the `country_id` to numeric:

```
country_id = input(substr(key, 2, 3), best.);
```

Your current code is literally just taking the three characters '036' and storing them in `country_id` as a text value; the `input()` function converts it to numeric.